# Temperature Effects

Tags: hardware

I understand the min temperature specification for a Pi is 0°C, but could I run it outside over a British winter,  which has reached 15°C below, without damaging it? Would this temperature cause practical problems in realty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

basically, there are three temperature-related factors:

1. condensation, the water could easily ruin your PCB
2. temperature expansion, frequent changes in temperature could easily lead to cracks in PCB and/or separation of BGA-mounted parts
3. lead-free solder becomes very brittle at low temperatures, you may easily remove a part or two by just dropping board on the floor.

so, if you run your RPi in the area of low humidity, the temperature is more or less constant and you don't drop the device, you'll be perfectly fine at -15°C.

Comment: Does anyone know what halt and hass specifications the Pi was subjected to during development. Theu probably had to subject it to well below the min quoted temp .